# Relation ManyToOne required cascade persist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem when try insert a new entity.

I have two entity, EquipoControl and Modelo,the relation is :

One equipoControl can have a single model.

This is my relationship to equipoControl

## EquipoControl.php

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Agc\ManagerBundle\Entity\Modelo", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idModelo", referencedColumnName="idModelo")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, escribe el modelo")
     */
    protected $modelo;
```

In my entity model I do nothing for the relationship.

## DefaultController

```
$emDefault = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager("customer_1");

                $equipoControl = new EquipoControl();

                $actividad = $em->getRepository('AgcManagerBundle:Actividad')
                                            ->findOneBy(array('idActividad' => $idActividad));

                $formulario = $this->createForm(new EquipoControlType(array()), $equipoControl);

                $formulario->handleRequest($request);//Este metodo asocia los datos del formulario a nuestro objeto

                if ($formulario->isValid()) {
                //$idEquipoControl = $equipoControl->getIdEquipoControl();
                //Necesito comprobar que el equipo no existe y no está instalado en otra actividad
                $equipoControlExiste=$emDefault->getRepository('AgcManagerBundle:EquipoControl')->findOneBy(array('codigo'=>$equipoControl->getCodigo()));
                if (! $equipoControlExiste) {//SI EL EQUIPO NO EXISTE 

                    $equipoControl->setInstaladoEn($user->getAdministracion()->getIdAdministracion()."_".$idActividad);
                    $emDefault->persist($equipoControl);
                    $emDefault->flush();


                    $equipoActividad = new EquiposActividades();
                    $equipoActividad->setEquipoControl($equipoControl);
                    $actividadObj=$em->getRepository('AgcManagerBundle:Actividad')->findOneBy(array('idActividad'=>$idActividad));
                    $equipoActividad->setActividad($actividadObj);
                    $equipoActividad->setIdUsuario($user->getIdUser());
                    $tipoTransmision = new TipoTransmision();
                    $tipoTransmision->setIdTipoTransmision(0);
                    $protocolo = new Protocolo();
                    $protocolo->setIdProtocolo(0);
                    $equipoActividad->setTipoTransmision($tipoTransmision);
                    $equipoActividad->setProtocolo($protocolo);

                    $em->persist($equipoActividad);
                    $em->flush();

                    $message='El equipo se ha instalado convenientemente...Puede realizar su configuración.';
                    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success',$message);
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('agc_asistente_actividad', array("paso" => "4"))."?equipoactividad=".$equipoActividad->getIdEquipoActividad());//Redireccion a otro sitio
                    }
```

When I insert a new EquipoControl in my form, skip the error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Agc\ManagerBundle\Entity\EquipoControl#modelo' that was not
>   configured to cascade persist operations for entity: ESD 123SR. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

I need not persist, I just want to assoc

Answer (score -1):

Your association is mapped correctly. You need persist the `Modelo` entity before persisting your `EquipoControl` entity.

What happens most likely is that the `Modelo` to which your associating your `EquipoControl` doesn't exist or is not persisted yet. Thus doctrine can't persist the association and suggests you to *cascade* it.

**Update:**

If you already have the `Modelo` entities persisted in the database, you need first load the `Modelo` then associate it to `EquipoControl`.

***Example:***

```
...
$entityManager = new EntityManager();
$equipo = new EquipoControl();
$modelo = $entityManager->find('Modelo', 1234);
$equipo->setModelo($modelo);
$entityManager->persist();
$entityManager->flush();
...
```

**Update2:**

The problem is caused by the fact that you are trying to persist an instance of `EquipoControl` which has the property `$modelo` null.

It looks like this statement doesn't properly populate the `$equipoControl->modelo` property.

```
$formulario = $this->createForm(new EquipoControlType(array()), $equipoControl);
```

You need to extract the `modelo` manually form the form and set it in the `$equipoControl` object.

Comment: i have my models insert, only want relationship, no persist :(

Comment: To get this right, you already have the `Modelo`s in the database? and you want to associate the `EquipoControl`?

Comment: See the updated answer, with an example for existing `Modelo`.

Comment: I reviewed the charts and models equipocontrol in mysql, and are not related.
could that be the problem?

Comment: Not really. The existence of foreign keys (based on which chart relation are drawn) doesn't affect persistence. Have you tested my suggestion above?

Comment: i have a form, in this, show fields of the entity equipoControl, and the entity model is selected in a option choices, i want that model is assoc the id in my entity equipocontrol

Comment: Ahh.. well, you will have to get your hands dirty and see what happens in the controller unfortunately :). There is were the problem resides most likely. You'll have to make sure your `Modelo` instance is properly loaded with the `EntityManager` and then properly set in your new `EquipoControl` object before persisting it.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think for now you have a good set of clues on why it doesn't work. Let me know the solution when you find it.